# Arranging text widgets in one row.Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added four text widgets in one sidebar,
these sidebars are generated in four rows, one below the other.

What I want is to show them in one single row side-by-side.

I found `class WP_Widget_Text` in `default-widgets.php`, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: "I have added four text widgets in one sidebar", show us some code thanks :D

Comment: i created a sidebar and drag and dropped four text widgets in it.i did this way not through coding.

Comment: Without some code (even in some IDE or Editor you can see the code) we can't help you much.

Comment: it is possible from wordpress admin section.i am using wordpress 3.8

Comment: But now we know that you use WordPress, state that in your post, maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is add the following code in style.css

```
    <style type='text/css'>
        .textwidget {
            display:inline;
            margin-left: 10px;
            float:left;
        }
    </style>
```

you can also remove `div` tag from line 403

```
echo $before_widget;
if ( !empty( $title ) ) { echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; } ?>
     echo !empty( $instance['filter'] ) ? wpautop( $text ) : $text; 
echo $after_widget;
```

but this can't be a guaranteed solution, because $before_widget, $after_widget can output some code that can create div / add line breaks.

both these solutions are not update friendly. i.e. if you update WordPress or change your theme, you will see it won't work.

The best solution I feel is use one text widget, with some CSS as below.

```
<div style='float:left;display:block inline;margin-right:10px'>Widget text 1</div>
<div style='float:left;margin-right:10px'>Widget text 2</div>
<div style='float:left;margin-right:10px'>Widget text 3</div>
<div style='float:left'>Widget text 4</div>
```

you will have to use inline css. you can also add border and other styling to seprate the `div's` currently i have just added right margin

Comment: i am trying first method.you said remove <div> tag,but i have to replace it with something.